# How to send files to webmethod along with other data? Without using any plug in

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ok so I have a couple of input fields etc I send the data of these field to server side webmethod . WHich is working fine. But I also want to send files to the same webmethod (and not ashx hander) alond with the data of other input fields. Can you please help me out?

**This calls webmethod which stored data in database**

```
function SendToServer(name,lineitems) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.aspx/PostDataWM",
                data: JSON.stringify({ name: name,lineitems: lineitems }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data, status) {
//                    console.log("CallWM");
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

**File Upload MarkUp**

```
  <span style="font-family: Arial">Click to add files</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="add" onclick="AddFileUpload()" />
        <br />
<br />
        <div id="FileUploadContainer">
            <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->
        </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var counter = 0;
         function AddFileUpload() {
             var div = document.createElement('DIV');
             div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter + '" type="file" class="clsFileUpload" /><input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
             document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
             counter++;
         }
         function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
             document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
         }
     </script>
```

**WebMethod**

```
   [WebMethod(enableSession: true)]    
    public static string PostDataWM(string name,string lineitems)
    {
     //blah blah
    }
```

Comment: add name and lineitems hidden inputs to your file upload form

Comment: @dandavis let me try that

Comment: @dandavis it worked. I didn't think of that before.Thanks. But just out of curiosity if I want to do this in the webmethod is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can use FormData() to attach files to ajax POSTs, or you can write a custom handler and post the base64 file data as string variables.

Comment: Not the handler , i would like to get data along with files in the same webmethod. I dont think I can use HttpContext in WebMethod.

Answer (score 0):

No need to stringify the data. 
 Try it directly. You can get data at your code level

```
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/PostDataWM",
            data: { name: name,lineitems: lineitems },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
```